# Adding function from parent theme to child theme

Tags: child-theme

I need to edit a few files that are part of a parent theme that I am using. I have put them in the child theme folder.

Now I need to deal with the function for it.

This is the function in the parent theme's functions.php file. The function references the files that I need to edit and of course I could edit them in the parent theme but then that defeats the purpose of a child theme with theme updates.

```
function kioken_builder_init() {

    if(is_admin()){

    if ( defined('WPB_VC_VERSION') ) {        

        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/k_image.php');
        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/team.php');
        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/additionals.php');
        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/testimonial_slider.php');    

        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/types/iconselector.php');
        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/types/kioconpicker.php');
        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/types/dropdown_multi.php');


    }      
    }

}

add_action('admin_init', 'kioken_builder_init');

if (defined('WPB_VC_VERSION')) {
        $tmpdir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/kioken/functions/builder/vc_templates/';
        vc_set_template_dir($tmpdir);
        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/builder_row.php');
        require_once (KIO_FUNC_DIR . 'builder/builder_column.php');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your child functions file, try:

```
remove_action('admin_init', 'kioken_builder_init');

function ben_kioken_builder_init() {

    if ( defined('WPB_VC_VERSION') ) {         
       //etc
    }    
}
add_action('admin_init', 'ben_kioken_builder_init');
```

You don't need the `if(is_admin())` check because admin_init only fires on admin pages.

Comment: The child functions file loads before the parent functions file, so I have doubts about this solution. That is, `kioken_builder_init`will be hooked in after you try to remove it. Have you tested this solution?

Comment: Ah, load order issues. No I haven't tested. So how do you remove an add_action from a parent theme?

Comment: Look at the priority parameter for add_action. You will need to be clever with that.

Comment: @shanebp that didn't give me any errors but I think its seeing the folder/files? Unless I put the other code after the add action but I don't think I need that.